# Plural should be used on decimal quantities?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In following situations, should we use singular or plural?

> 1. I have 300 units of goods and this will last 0.8 [month | months].
> 2. I have 1,000 units and this will last 2.5 [month | months].

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Related question from ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile

Comment: #2 doesn't really seem to be about decimals - 2.5 is definitely more than one month, so it's clearly plural whether there's a decimal point or not.

Comment: Also related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90014/0-4-point-or-0-4-points-1-0-point-or-1-0-points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the plural for both.

As [the linked ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile) says, the only time to use the singular form with a number is for a quantity of *exactly* one, and if that one is being expressed as a decimal (1.0), it might well still use the plural:

- 1 month
- 0.5 months
- 1.2 months
- 1.0 months

If you're describing a fraction using words it becomes more complicated - fractions less than one still use the singular:

- one month
- half a month
- a quarter of a month
- one and a half months
- two months

Comment: To remember this: it's always the word directly before month(s) that determines whether it's singular or plural. It's only singular if it's 'the', 'a' or 'one'.