# Plural with decimals

Tags: singular-vs-plural, numbers

I am trying to determine the proper way to write tenths of a mile in press releases.

So is it from 0.5 miles north to 0.2 miles south of FM 12? Or from 0.5 mile north to 0.2 mile south of FM 12?

And is it proper to write .2 miles or 0.2 miles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plural should be used on decimal quantities?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103682/plural-should-be-used-on-decimal-quantities)

Answer (score 9):

When writing academically or for publication, consult the relevant style guide.
Most style guides advise that decimals are to be expressed as plural whether there is a whole part (e.g. 1.25) or not (e.g. 0.6), examples: 1.25 miles, 0.6 tons.

> Decimal quantities are considered to be plural; quantities expressed
>   as fractions are considered to be singular. So write “0.8 miles” but
>   “eight tenths of a mile.” For decimal forms, only the number one is
>   singular: 1 mile. Once you add a decimal, even if it's a zero, it
>   becomes plural: 1.0 miles.

[Numbers - Chicago Manual of Style (FAQ)](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers/faq0058.html)

Regarding 'leading zeros' in decimals, or not, (e.g. '0.9' versus '.9') this is also a matter of style.

> If a value has the potential to exceed 1.0, use the leading zero. If a
>   value can never exceed 1.0, do not use the leading zero.

[APA Style blog 'A post about nothing'](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/07/a-post-about-nothing.html)

Comment: Perfect! This is the answer I've been seeking. Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, what about leading zeroes in integers? 001 mile or 001 miles?

Comment: @geekley - Why would anyone write 'It is 002 miles from my work to my house'? Is that what you are asking about? This is an English site. Software/UI design is off topic. Can you think of a convincing reason why it should not be 001 mile and 002+ miles?

Comment: Yeah, I meant in context of software, not necessarily formal text. Sorry if it's off-topic, but it's relevant information. I do suppose it's 001 mile, but I'm not native, so I can't know for sure. English does have weird things such as 0 being plural, which is different from my language, where [0~1.999...) interval is singular. And the exception of 1.0 miles being plural, to me, seems just as arbitrary as 001 miles; so I wouldn't know. -- For context, my library/format will deal with internationalization and I need to get plurality right, so it helps to know these specifics.