# Is it 1.7 times or 1.7 time? How about 0.7 time/times? Or something else?

Tags: mathematics

There is a similar question asked about temperature [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244256/proper-way-to-say-one-1-5-times-more), but I'm asking more generally and without the convenience of the difference being a nice half.

If Alice has 10 grams of sugar and Bob has 17 grams of sugar, does Bob have 1.7 **times** the amount of sugar that Alice has, or does Bob have 1.7 **time** the amount of sugar that Alice has?

Similarly, does Bob have 0.7 **times** more sugar than Alice, or does he have 0.7 **time** more sugar? I explicitly ask about this separately because it is a multiple that is less than 1.

All my life, I've used **times** in both cases. I remember purposely making this decision but I don't remember why. Maybe someone can tell me how I'm right or wrong, or whether all of these are incorrect.

Comment: When discussing multiplication, or saying aloud the multiplication sign `×` it's always 'times' with a final 's' whether or not either side of the calculation is less than one. Zero point seven times zero point six equals zero point four two.

Comment: If you use "times" as in multiply, it requires an s. This isn't a plural marker.  Times is a verb, the s is for the third person singular agreement.  So, for example: one times eight is one.

Comment: It grinds my gears when some Brits say (e.g.) 'to double a number, times it by two'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - just like it grates on my nerves when Americans say "math". LOL

Comment: @BillyKerr - yes, indeed. For clarity, I am British!

Comment: See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/234439/138287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a common situation, but you should use "times" in all cases. The singular is used for exactly 1, and plural is used for other values, including fractions, zero and even negative multipliers.

You'll see the most often with units.  You day 0.7 grammes, not 0.7 gram.  Even "minus one Coulombs" of electric charge is correct.

Comment: This answer is correct about the use of "times", but I have seen scientific textbooks where the singular is used for units of measurements when the magnitude of a number is 1 or less, but not zero. Note that unit abbreviations should *never* be plural, as the "s" will be understood to mean "second". For example 2 Ws is not understood as 2 watts, but as 2 watt seconds, which is the same as 2 joules (2 J).

Comment: We would say or write 0.5 or 0.7 grammes, but half, or seven tenths, of one (or a) gramme.

Comment: 'The singular is used for exactly 1' is confusing here. One times seventeen is seventeen; one times one is one. In spelling out the binary operation, no matter what the numbers, 'times' is always used. It corresponds to 'plus' / 'add', 'take', and 'divided by'. All are invariant.

Comment: I remember being taught the "times table" at primary school. I can't remember if we started with "one" or "two" for the first number, but I'm quite sure we started with "one" for the *second.* Google NGrams is case-sensitive, so probably most instances of [***One times one is one***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=One+times+one+is+one&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) reflect schoolchildren chanting their tables.